# How to update the same field with condition in Python Dataset?

Tags: python, mysql, dataset

I have mysql query look like this: update user set password = 12345 where password = 11111

And in Python Dataset will be:

```
document = { "id_user": 1, "password": "12345" }    
result = con.load_table("user").update(document, ["password"])
```

The question is how can I pass condition or value update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i figured out right what you want to do. But if you want to update your Python dataset you can easily do this with the following code:

```
document["password"] = "11111"
```

You are also able to use variables to update your dataset

```
test = "1111"
document["password"] = test
```

To update your Dataset according to a specific condition you probably have to loop through your SQL results in a for loop and change the specific dataset

Comment: how to convert to dataset update from mysql: update user set password = 12345 where password = 11111 and id_user = 1. my problem is can not pass data and condition at the same time